# How to Save data into Project Folder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, save

I download a XML file from web and save it in a folder.With these Codes

```
NSURL *goo = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"......xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:goo]; 
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/Users/MacBook/Desktop/Bebegim_Icin_Yarisiyorum/Milyoner/Class";   
NSString *xmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"qpack1.xml"];
[xml writeToFile:xmlFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Class Folder is in myProject Folders.

But Apple does not have this path.I need to say save the 
xml file in Class folder of My project Folders.

```
/Users/MacBook/Desktop/Bebegim_Icin_Yarisiyorum/Milyoner/Class
```

Can anyone help me,I should say `../Class` or `.Class` or `./Class`?

What should I say when I am creating documentDirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/qpack2.xml"];
```

Or:

```
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
NSString *docsPAth = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"qpack2.xml"];
```

Comment: Thx for your answer,I tried both of your codes it didnt work.It didnt save the xmlfile from web or I couldnt make.my problem is after I downloaded the Xml file I am reading it.It works well on my mac.But when I load it to appstore it wont work because of xml file path.

Comment: The documentsDirectory exists on the device, you should be able to save it there.